# Issue with Status Bar Icon Not Displaying in macOS Flutter App

Tags: swift, objective-c, flutter, macos, swiftui

I'm developing a macOS application using Flutter and I've encountered an issue where the status bar statusItem are not displaying on some computers. Below is the relevant portion of my AppDelegate.swift code.
Icon and Text are both not display.

```
override func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
           mainFlutterWindow?.setContentSize(NSSize(width: 800, height: 400));

           //---------------stuts--------------------
            statusBarItem = NSStatusBar.system.statusItem(withLength: NSStatusItem.variableLength)
            if let button = statusBarItem.button {
                if let iconImage = NSImage(named: NSImage.Name("icon_64")) {
                    iconImage.size = NSSize(width: 16, height: 16) 寸
                    button.image = iconImage
                    button.title = "A"
                } else {
                    // 如果图标为空，则输出错误信息
                    print("Error: AppIcon not found")
                    button.title = "AAA"
                }
                button.action = #selector(toggleMenu(_:))
            }
            // 创建退出菜单项
            let menu = NSMenu()

            // 开机启动菜单项
            let autoStartMenuItem = NSMenuItem(title: "Auto start", action: #selector(toggleAutoStart(_:)), keyEquivalent: "")
            autoStartMenuItem.state = isAutoStartEnabled() ? .on : .off

            menu.addItem(autoStartMenuItem)
            // 快捷键
            menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Shortcut key", action: #selector(setShortcutKey), keyEquivalent: ""))
            // 退出
            menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "Quit", action: #selector(quitApp), keyEquivalent: "q"))
            statusBarItem.menu = menu
}
```

I've checked the icon file and it seems to be in order. There are no console errors indicating a problem with the file or the code.

The issue does not occur on all machines - it works fine on some but not on others. I haven't been able to determine a pattern or reason behind this inconsistency.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue or could provide insights into what might be going wrong? How can I ensure the status bar icon displays consistently across all macOS versions and systems in a Flutter macOS application?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!